# Explanation regarding skipping of alternate lines while reading from a file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I just want to know, have I interpreted the code in right manner?

The file `Bharath.txt` has the following content:

> Hello ! B . We created your file succesfully . We have updated you file , Sir !    Bharath   Nikhil   Friends Indeed

Consider the below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class FilInpStr
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream obj=new FileInputStream("Bharath.txt");
        Scanner input=new Scanner(obj);

        String n="";
        while((n=input.nextLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(n);
        }

    }
}
```

The above code works well this way. But when I do not consider storing  `input.nextLine()` in a `String`, it begins to skip line alternatively. Is it that it is taking even the <kbd>Enter</kbd> from keyboard as input?

So, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it is passing the escape sequence too, as an input, which is why it is skipping one and printing the other?

And another doubt was regarding the while loop: is that one line wasted while comparing whether it is `null` or not?

1. Bharath
2. Nikhil
3. Friends Indeed

So, when I quote:

```
while((input.nextLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(input.nextLine());
}
```

It will check whether `Bharath==null` or not, and if not, it will only then print `Nikhil`? And post `Nikhil`, it will skip next line, because it takes <kbd>Enter</kbd> as an escape sequence.

Please, correct me! I might have mixed up two different approaches. A beginner hence.

Also, do mention in distinction the difference between passing the `input.nextLine()` into a `String`, and as standalone code.

Answer (score 4):

> But , when I do not consider storing " input.nextLine()" in a String , it begins to skip line alternatively . Is it , that , it is taking even the ENTER from keyboard as input ?

Well no, it's just reading the next line every time you call `input.nextLine()`. That shouldn't be surprising. Ignore escape sequences etc. For the sake of simplicity, assume that `input.nextLine()` is just reading from a list of strings somewhere... it has a cursor showing where on the list it is. Every time you call `input.nextLine()`, it returns the current line and moves the cursor down.

If you call `input.nextLine()` twice in each iteration (once in the `while` condition and once inside the body) then you'll only execute half as many iterations as if you call it *once* per iteration (as per your original code).

Comment: To add more , will it be correct to say : that its use twice : " Once in "while" and , once inside body " are like two individual statements ? and not the same . I mean , while is for 1st , and the body for 2nd , and again 3rd for while , and 4th for body , again ?

Comment: @1ambharath: Once in the *condition* and once in the *body*. The body is still within the while statement... it's the body *of* the while statement.

Comment: Ok . So , when I initialize the string with input.nextLine() , I am basically passing the same statement in the body too .Unlike , the previous code , thatt is getting executed twice  Hence , it works well . Right ?

Comment: @1ambharath: Don't focus on "same statement" - just focus on "the condition calls `nextLine()` and so does the body of the loop, so you're calling it twice when you don't want to.

Comment: I see the clarity now.

Answer (score 1):

```
input.nextLine()
```

Does two things :

1. Return the value of the current line
2. Advance the *cursor* past the current line

[Scanner.nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped.

So, if you don't store the result of `input.nextLine()`, it will be lost.

Each call to `input.nextLine()` advances past the current line, so each call will read a **different** part of the input.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the second snippet isn't the storing, but the fact you call `nextLine()` **twice** in each iteration. First, you call it in the `while` loop - the line is read and is then ignored (i.e., not saved anywhere), but the internal cursor of the input stream is advanced to the next line. Then, in the `println` line, you read another line and return it to `System.out.println`, effectively having all the odd-numbered lines just ignored.